# How to use downloaded nuget packages

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, prism-5

I have downloaded a Nuget Package (Prism 5.0) and added it to current project.

Now I have created a new solution and i want to add reference to previously downloaded Prism package. But it is not shown anywhere in downloaded packages.
Only option appear is to get it downloaded again.

How to keep only one copy of downloaded nuget packages, and reuse them later ?

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you always do the normal way. That is always add a nuget package from the Package manager Console or Manage Nuget Package extension.Yes they will be downloaded every time you add them.

But sure there is another way where in you use the previously downloaded packages.

When you download a package they are cached in the nuget cache at C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache

You can create a package source using these cached version by going to Tools > Options > PackageManager > Package Sources

Scott Hanselman has a detailed blog (with screen shots) on this topic http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx